# event.target.value returning [object Object] instead of the value

Tags: lightning-web-components

**I need to get the value of the selected radio button.Is there any other way to do it?Because event.target.value prints [object Object]**

```
getSelectedValues(event){
    this.radioButton = event.target.value;
    console.log('event.target.value : '+event.target.value);
    console.log('Selected value : '+this.radioButton);
}
```

```
<input type="radio" name={con} value={item} style="margin-right: 5px;" onclick={getSelectedValues} >
```

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `{item}`?

Comment: @DavidReed It is of list type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify like this:

```
console.log('event.target.value : ' + JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

`[Object Object]` comes when you try to reference an object.

Try this :

```
var objB = {test:213};
alert(objB);
```

---

```
var objB = {test:213};
alert(objB.test);
```

In your chrome developer console. The first one shows `[object Object]` and the second one shows `213`.

debug it and try to fetch the property of the object. That should give you the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value as a string by e.target.value. then you can filter that from selected array of object.
const data = {key1:'data1',key2:[{...},{...}]};

here you are targeting the value from key2 in radio button.

const fun = ()=>{
const filteredData = data.key2.filter((para)=>para.key==e.target.value);
}